# How can I use the id of an element to trigger an event in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, dom, meteor, dom-events

I am currently using Meteor 0.6.3

**The following scenario, using the 'id' as selector, doesn't work:**

*Template:*

```
<template name="menu">
    <div>
        <button id="showmap" class="btn-primary">Show map</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

*JS:*

```
Template.menu.events({
  'click #showmap' : function () {
      alert("test");
  }
});
```

If I use a 'class' instead of the 'id' everything works fine:

*Template:*

```
<template name="menu">
    <div>
        <button class="btn-primary showmap">Show map</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

*JS:*

```
Template.menu.events({
  'click .showmap' : function () {
      alert("test");
  }
});
```

I have seen several examples of people using 'id' as selector. So what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I assume there is no chance you have multiple elements with the ID = "showmap" eh?  if you do a `$("#showmap")` it doesn't show you more than one?  Docs don't explicitly talk about selector support, but they certainly do find `input[id]` for preserve... http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps

Comment: Your code looks perfectly correct. I'd second @zeroasterisk, that's the only thing I can think of that could be causing the problem.

Comment: I only have one item with the id. Anyway if I set up the trigger with jQuery for example `$('#showmap').click(function() { .... })` there is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and it doesn't work like you said. Strange thing is the event for the class selector doesn't work either. However, I have lots of packages added on, so I wouldn't be surprised if one of them is interfering.

I found this response on SO to a very similar question:
[Setting simple events in meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112930/setting-simple-events-in-meteor)

So you might want to search through the bug reports and post it if it isn't already posted.
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues

The best workaround is probably to use class as the selector and then test against `event.currentTarget.id` which should have the id of the element clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I use attributes. ID doesn't seem to work for me too. For example:

```
<button data-do-something>
  Click Me
</button>


'click [data-do-something]': function(eventArgs, template){

}
```

Good thing about attributes is that you can also assign values to the attributes, and use them with the events. for example:

```
<button data-do-something="hello">
  Click Me
</button>


'click [data-do-something]': function(eventArgs, template){
    var data = eventArgs.target.getAttribute('data-do-something');
    if(data === 'hello') console.log('found hello!");
}
```

Comment: It should be  `var data = eventArgs.target.getAttribute('data-do-something'); `